# Is there any way to check if file exists in Apache beam sdk without using pipeline

Tags: java, file, apache-beam

I am currently trying to check if file exists on cluster by using the MatchResult status. Even if the file exists it is returning the status as NOT_FOUND.

```
MatchResult matchResult = FileSystems.match(output string)

if(matchResult.status() == MatchResult.Status.NOT_FOUND){
//do some operation 
//print file does not exist
}
else{
//print file exists
}
```

the above code is returning status as not found even if file exists.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `==` instead of `=`? You want to compare instead of assign

Comment: Yes i was using == , sorry for the typo. Corrected in question

Answer (score 0):

What kind of file system is on your cluster? AFAIK, Beam file system supports only S3, GCS, HDFS and local FS.
Also, it would worth to print out "matchResult" and see the full path if it matches with your real path on cluster.

Comment: HDFS file system is being used and tried printing the matchResult status and path which it is taking. Path does exist on HDFS but the result is NOT_FOUND.